# Android custom adapter with imageview and textview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the following xml layout for my custom adapter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When i inflate this custom layout(for a listview) the textview has a large gap beacuse of the image view.I want to be able to show the textview below one another and the image view to the right. How di i do this.

Comment: You don't have `EditTexts` in your layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Relativelayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="TextView" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```